# Best way to display domain object summary information efficiently and in an OO way from a large inheritance tree?

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, design

**I've provided only simplified code as it's more of an abstract design question.**

So I have many, many nested business/domain event objects, e.g.

```
 public class Event
 {
  //bunch of properties and standard accessors
 }

 public class ExplosionEvent extends Event
 {
  //properties and standard accessors 
 }
```

And many more of these at different levels.  If I need information about any given object chosen, I display it in HTML like so

```
 private String generateHTML(Event event)
 { 
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   sb.append("<HTML><table>");//simplified

   sb.append("<TH>Time</TH>");   
   sb.append("<TD>" + event.getEventTime() + "</TD>");

   if (event instanceof ExplosionEvent)
   {
     //append HTML and ExplosionEvent specific data
   }

   // ...many, many more calls like the one above

   sb.append("</table></HTML>");
 }
```

As I have many event types, this means loads of duplicated HTML table tags and uses of `instanceof` so `generateHTML` is hundreds of lines long, split into methods of course but still, it's a lot of code that makes this hard to understand, navigate and therefore maintain.

This is ugly and I need a better design for this.  I had the idea of creating a method on `Event` which is overridable by all sub methods

```
//Using LinkedHashMap to preserve order as Properties wont do that
public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getAttributes()
{
 LinkedHashMap<String, String> list = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

 list.put("Time", eventTime);
}
```

sub-classes then override this, call their parent and add date specific to them to the list meaning that no matter how many `Event` classes there is, the existing `generateHTML` method (external to `Event` objects) will then simply be one small loop

```
private String generateHTML(Event event)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  b.append("<HTML><table>");

  for (Entry<String,String> entry : event.getAttributes().entrySet())
  {
    sb.append("<TH>" + entry.getKey() + "</TH>");   
    sb.append("<TD>" + entry.getValue() + "</TD>");
  }

  sb.append("</table></HTML>");
}
```

Is this putting too much logic in business/domain objects?

**Is there a better way**?

Comment: Nobody on Programmers have some ideas?

Comment: This is _exactly_ the issue that OCP (Open-Closed Principle) addresses. This is well documented and I suggest looking this up rather than having someone here regurgitate this well-known good practice advice.

Comment: As an aside, your code is not "nested". Inheritance graphs are not the same as nesting.

Answer (score 3):

This looks suspicious to me ...

```
if (event instanceof ExplosionEvent)
{
  //append HTML and ExplosionEvent specific data
}
```

... usually when I see that I think that Event ought to be abstract with an overridable method. That method be `LinkedHashMap<String, String> getAttributes()` as you suggested.

Another possibility is to store the LinkedHashMap as a member of Event (pseudo-code ahead):

```
class Event
{
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> map;
    protected void SetAttribute(String name, String value)
    {
        // stores in map
    }
    protected String getAttribute(String name)
    {
        // gets from map
    }
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> getAttributes()
    {
        // returns entire map
    }
}

class ExplosionEvent inherits Event
{
    String getLocation() { return getAttribute("location"); }
    void setLocation(String location) { setAttribute("location", location); }

}
```

---

You could consider using the [`java.utils.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) for your implementation.

---

Another solution might be to [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6800341/49942).

Comment: I hate `instanceof` myself, that and the duplicated table HTML.   It's been suggested by colleagues that my solution is wrong because it places processing into objects which is wrong.

Comment: If someone adds a new property to the `ExplosionEvent` subclass then they'll need to edit your `generateHTML` method too, which IMO is <strike>no better</strike> worse. To be 'object oriented' the base Event class should either contain (see `java.utils.Properties`) or abstract the list of properties; or use reflection; or (similar to refelction) use auto-generated ORM code somehow (define properties as XML and auto-gererate the Java code for the event subclasses and the `generateHTML` method).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad solution because it mixes two completely separate concerns - your objects' primary functions, and outputting its properties as HTML. On the other hand, I imagine you're trying to get access to the object's private state, which violates abstraction.

If you're only trying to print out this HTML for debugging purposes, the best solution would be to use reflection to inspect its fields/properties. If you only need to print out some fields, you can use annotations to mark which fields are meant to be inspected with reflection.

If providing access to its fields is part of the design then your classes should provide a your `getAttributes` as part of an interface, but delegate `generateHTML` to someone else. That way you don't have to change your classes just because you want to change the HTML formatting. You can decouple the code further by returning `Map` or `Iterator` from `getAttributes` instead of `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: This is part of the design.  
In my solution mentioned I have a `getAttributes` function per `Event` which returns attributes as key and value pair.  In the part currently generating HTML, it will still do so, just doing it as a loop using the key and value pair from each event.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty obvious, object-oriented and simple way would be to add the `generateHtml()` method into the `Event` objects.

I.e. have the events generate their own view. I would perhaps not call it `generateHtml()`, but something like `displaySummary()`. That fits better with *what* it does, and not how it does it, or with which technology.

If you have commonalities between events, you could try to create a common display widget for it. For example `DataPanel` to display label-value pairs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution of implementing `generateHTML()` and overriding it in subclasses is indeed a common object oriented approach, but as noticed, it puts unrelated logic or functionality into business objects.

This can be avoided by implementing a double dispatch which is essentially a simplified version of the visitor pattern:

- Implement an abstract class (or interface) `EventVisitor` with methods `visitEvent()`, `visitExplosionEvent()` etc. and a class `EventHTMLGenerator` which subclasses the superclass or implements the interface. Of course, the visitor class must know about the visited objects, and depending on your language it must be a friend class or the `Event` attributes must be otherwise accessible to it.
- In your `Event` class, implement an `accept()` method that takes a `Visitor` argument and calls its `visitEvent()` method. Override `accept()` in each subclass to call the appropriate `visitX()` method

The visitor pattern is often used to traverse recursive object structures such as syntax trees, but this doesn't apply here, so your `visitX()` methods would not need to call `accept()` recursively.

Of course, this leads to somewhat more code, but it keeps everything related to HTML generation for `Event`s in one place.